# Identifying this spider

Tags: species-identification, arthropod

I think this is a spider. 8 legs, 2 body sections, and 2 really long Palos? Anyways, can anyone identify this bug, or point me to a resource where I could classify it?[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please include your location and an approximate size of the species. And also add multiple close-up images from different sides. See [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) for more information

Comment: That's not a spider, that's a solifuge (also an Arachnida): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solifugae .[@Anon answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/60898/24284) is correct, despite lacking any reference or image for comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's camel spider, they have large pedipalps, big chelicerae, and their body is covered by little "hairs". As far as I know, there are only 2 families of that order in North America

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please add some more details and references to your answer, along with some images for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Some spider species are easy to identify as they're relatively common and well-known or though less common, have unusual or distinctive enough markings/coloration, they won't generally be mis-identified.

Since you live in the US, the species will be better identified by another American rather than someone from other another continent. Bug Guide (hosted by the Department of Entomology at Iowa State University) has an [ID Request](http://bugguide.net/node/view/6/bgimage) page where images can be posted and amateur and professional experts will look at and identify. You need to register but it's free. The clearer and more detailed your photo(s), the faster it'll be viewed and answered.

It's worth joining. There's a lot to learn and you may find learning about 'bugs' addictive with no bad effects?

Comment: I hardly think my answer warranted a downvote. Not living in the US, I didn't recognise it. The OP did ask for identification *OR* to be pointed to a resource that could help. BugGuide is an excellent resource for identifying arthropods.

Comment: I agree with @Jude: downvote might be justified if there was something misleading identification in the answer, but here there is no identification attempt. One could argue that this could have more typically been a comment rather than an answer, but given the fact that the original poster requested for identification resources, this may qualify as an answer.